# Is it possible for Eclipse to autocomplete based on not just first few letters

Tags: ide, eclipse

In several IDEs I'm familiar with (Visual Studio with Visual Assist, Qt Creator and Intellij IDEA), the autocompletion feature can give suggestions based not just on the first few letters. For example, if I have two methods named `encryptByAES`, `encrpytByDES` and start typing "eD", then the IDE will prompt `encryptByDES`.

I'm currently trying Eclipse, and the above does not work in default configuration. I have to type all the "encryptByD" to get it to recognize that I mean the second one. If I just type "eD", then content assistant simply does not know what I mean. The question is, is it possible to get the same behavior in Eclipse?

Comment: If you type "eBD" it works. You have to indicate the "B" in encryptByDES since it's a capital letter.

Comment: you might want to take a look at [Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/)